# LWC Rich Text component doesn't trigger change event, value not updated on blur, for minor changes

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputrichtext

I was experimenting with with the [`lightning-input-rich-text`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text) component and followed the instructions for a simple use-case. Everything renders as expected but, when I started typing, the `change` event did not fire. When I switched to `blur`, the `e.target.value` seemed to be stuck on the initial value. It didn't show the changes I'd made.

After more experimenting, it appears that simply typing text into the input doesn't cause an update, but <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd> and arrow keys (<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>) do cause both an internal update and a `change` event. If I delete a character, add a space, or make a change and then navigate with the arrow keys, then the `onchange` event handlers are called and the `onblur` event handlers show all changes since the last space/backspace/arrow key.

Is this documented behavior? It's a pretty major issue if small changes are ignored unless the end-user presses a magical key! For example, adding a missing letter to a word won't trigger a `change` event and won't show up in a `blur` event unless the end-user taps an arrow key!

Here is the simple use-case component I created:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class PageContainer extends LightningElement {
    directValue = "<strong>Direct</strong>";

    testhandler(e) {
        debugger;
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    indirectValue = "<strong>Indirect</strong>";

    test = {
        handler(e) {
            debugger;
            console.log(e.target.value);
        }
    };

}
```

```html
<template>
    <h1>Direct</h1>
    <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={directValue}
        onblur={testhandler}
        onchange={testhandler}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
    <h1>Indirect</h1>
    <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={indirectValue}
        onblur={test.handler}
        onchange={test.handler}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</template>
```

When I add a few characters to the beginning, middle or end of the default content, the rich text input seems to ignore my changes. When I click away from the component, the `blur` event handler fires, but with the old content, as if nothing had changed.

### 1. Input updated:

[image]

### 2. No `change` event fires

### 3. The `blur` event fires, but `e.target.value` still shows the initial value:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Calling `e.target.setRangeText("", 0, 0)` will flush out any changes without changing/corrupting them (though note that the editor might standardize some of the formatting, like wrapping the content in `<p>` tags).

So, in the `onblur` event handler, add the above before attempting to read the value:

```
richTextBlurred(e) {
  e.target.setRangeText("", 0, 0);
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Note that this will trigger a `change` event, so if you are listening for both events, be prepared to handle the redundancy of these events.

Before calling `setRangeText()`:

[image]

After calling `setRangeText()`:

[image]